# What can be faulty on my clutch system ? Mustang '67

Tags: ford, clutch, manual-transmission, mustang, clutch-cable

I've ran out of ideas, haven't had the time to go under the car so I would like to know your opinion. I was riding my '67 Mustang, until gears suddenly felt stiff to engage, afterwards I realized the clutch wasn't engaging. I went under the hood and tightened the adjustment rod and then the clutch became all right. Although, 20 miles ahead it did the same thing all over again, and now I have reached the max of my adjustment rod, so I am not sure what the problem is. The cable has less than 2 years and seems in a great shape. Do you guys have any idea what can be behind this ?

Comment: Is the cable stretching?

Comment: 67 mustang does not have a clutch cable?

Comment: When you made the adjustment did you **tighten up the lock nut on the barrel adjuster ?**   You  may need a new clutch. The plate could be worn or the tension of the pressure  plate has failed or the throw-out bearing is sloppy on the arm.